# structured streaming metrics performance?

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, metrics, spark-structured-streaming

After trying some methods for monitoring structured streaming performance, input/output metrics, I see that a reliable way is to attach streamingQueryListener to output the streamingQueryProgress to get the input/output number.

Besides the SparkUI,

Is there any better way to monitor structured streaming performance?

What's the best way to output the queryProgress into a file or Kafka?

What's the efficient way to compare performance (speed, input, output record) between the spark streaming and spark structured streaming?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to use ELK stack.

Spark application can sink the jmx to Logstash, which is able to aggregate the data, and send the data to ElasticSearch for indexing.

Kibana is able to display the data from ElasticSearch with the visualization capabilities.

1) You need to either include spark-sql-kafka dependency in build.sbt, 
(at this moment, I am using Spark 2.2.0 with spark-sql-kafka 0.10)

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.0"
```

or includes --packages when doing spark-submit,

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0
```

2) In order for spark application to output the jmx, all the lines related to jmx need to be uncommented in the file metrics.properties,

And, during the spark-submit, pointing the file directory like below,

```
--files=metrics.properties --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties
```

3) Install ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana.

If you are in Window, the way to start the ELK stack like below,

```
C:\elasticsearch> .\bin\elasticsearch.bat

C:\logstash> bin\logstash.bat -f .\jmx.conf

C:\kibana> .\bin\kibana.bat
```

In the jmx.conf, jmx path and the polling frequency need to be configured.

```
input { 
   jmx {
     path => "C:/logstash/config/jmx/"
     polling_frequency => 15
     type => "jmx"
     nb_thread => 2
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   }
}
```

In the folder of jmx path, a json file need to be created to list the object_names and attributes that you want the Logstash to retrieve.
(Logstash will read this json file based on the polling_frequency, so any later update in this json file when the Spark applications are running, Logstash will pick up, meaning that no need to restart the Logstash)

You can list the available object_names and attributes from jconsole after you submit the Spark applications,

The sample file is as follows,

```
{
  "host" : "localhost",
  "port" : 9000,
  "alias" : "spark.jmx.sample1",
  "queries" : [
  {
    "object_name" : "kafka.consumer:type=consumer-metrics,client-id=*",
    "attributes" : ["incoming-byte-rate","outgoing-byte-rate"],
    "object_alias" : "byteRate"
  },
  {
    "object_name" : "metrics:name=local-1528139073457.driver.spark.streaming.e6c4b9da-a7d1-479f-b28f-ba2b9b1397d0.inputRate-total",
    "attrivutes" : ["Value"],
    "object_alias" : "somethingTeste1"
  }
]}
```

4) Finally, you will access the Kibana via http://localhost:5601

And, set up the index pattern first. (You should see the date of data index)

Then, go to visualization page to create the metrics with your object_names and attributes that you list from the jmx json file.